# genes with highest RPKM/FPKM for a human RNA-seq experiment?

Tags: rna-seq, ngs, illumina, human

Which genes/transcripts show up as having the highest RPKM/FPKM on a human RNA-seq experiment? Is it usually the same genes/transcripts?

EDIT: mRNAs (e.g. poly-A RNA-seq preps) and not including small RNAs.

Comment: What effort did you take? Did you look at available data from GEO already?

Comment: I'm guessing there's some missing context here of the form, "We've done a bunch of RNAseq experiments and X, Y, Z always show up as having the highest FPKMs. Have other people seen this or are we just doing something wrong?" If so, please include it.

Comment: @DevonRyan the context is more: "here is a handful of genes that always come up on top for a human sample. If you don't see them, something may have happened".

Comment: In that case, you may be looking for [housekeeping genes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Housekeeping_gene) -- this doesn't quite answer the question as stated (they aren't always the highest expressed, but they are usually present).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As asked as it is, the answer is probably no.

Indeed, the highest expressed RPKM/FPKMs will be different from one condition (or tissue) to another one for example.

Then, you may also have technical artefacts due to the wet-lab part or to the normalisation. For example, mitochondrial genes are often reported in the top expressed genes.

Now, if you want to compare your results to an outside source, I recommend checking the [EBI gene expression Atlas](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/gxa/home)* and more specifically the Baseline expression experiments.

Pro-tips:

- You can filter the genes based on their nature (eg, mRNA) and/or their expression.
- You can also visualise the overall expression of a specific gene across several experiments.

*Disclaimer: I am related to this project myself.